# Assigning the value to a column from a sql query

Tags: php, mysql

I have 2 tables and what I need is to selelct some of the columns from  table1 and copy those columns in the table2. I have tried many options but nothing is working for me. I am a beginner in the php and mysql field . These are the things that I have tried first.

```
 `$sql = " UPDATE table1 JOIN table2 ON  table1.primary_key = 
table2.primary_key  SET table1.column1= table2.column1 , table1.column2= 
table2.column2  WHERE table1.primary_key = 1  ";
```

and

```
`$sql= "update table1 set table1.column1 = 
table2.column1  FROM table1 INNER JOIN  
            table2 on table1.primary_key = 
 table2.primary_key WHERE table2.primary_key= 1 ";
```

and because of the reason that bothof them are not working, I tried another method:

```
              $sql= "SELECT column1,column2FROM table2 WHERE primary_key=1";
              $result = mysql_query($sql);
              $row = mysql_fetch_array($result);`
              $UpdateQuery ="UPDATE  table1 SET column1=$row[column1] ,column2=$row[column2] WHERE primary_key= 1";
                mysql_query($UpdateQuery);
```

This is also  throwing an error . Can any one tel me how to assign the column value from sql query or ny other methods that will satisfy my need .

Comment: If you are trying to insert one tables data in another table then use Insert why you are using Update

Comment: those rows you are trying to update from table2 to table1 are exist in table1 or you want to insert new rows into table1 after fetching from table2.

Comment: These rows already exist in the table1 @zafar Malik

Comment: as per your first query you want to update some columns of table1 where its primary id is 1 based on table2...if it is then your first query is fine, what issue you are getting.

Answer (score 0):

One option is to use a `JOIN` inside your SQL query during the `UPDATE`:

```
UPDATE table1 t1
JOIN
(
    SELECT * FROM table2
    WHERE table2.primary_key = 1
) t2
ON t1.primary_key = t2.primary_key
SET t1.column1 = t2.column1
```

I will leave it to you to insert this into your PHP code since so many details are not present in the original problem.

Answer (score 0):

When you want to insert data from a different table you can use insert... select statement available with mysql. 
Try like this:

```
INSERT INTO table1 (table1.column1,table1.column2) 
SELECT table2.column1,table2.column from table2
WHERE table1.primary_key = 1 
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE table1.column1= table2.column1 , table1.column2= 
table2.column2
```

For more information you can refer: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/insert-on-duplicate.html